# Requirement to display 3 mm LED by 220 V AC supply

Tags: led, capacitor, resistance, transformerless

I want to power a single 3 mm LED by a 220V AC source. For this I think I need one LED, one resistor and one capacitor. I don't know the needed resistor value and circuit diagram. The circuit also should tolerate changing voltages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This circuit involves dangerous mains voltage. Don't play with it or *always* keep one hand in your pocket while debugging.**

[This](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf) application note from Microchip has all the formulas you need.

This is a basic schematics:

[image]

And these are formulas:

[image]

To flash the LED, you don't need everything that is on this schematic. You don't need a regulated voltage, so you can drop D1. Since a LED is a diode, you can replace D2 with a LED. The LED will flash depending on frequency of your mains - 50 or 60 hz. You have to put two LEDs in antiparallel, so each LED flashed on positive and negative half-cycle.

The most minimal circuit that can light up a couple of LEDs is this:

[image]

But remember **this is high voltage that can kill you**.

Comment: Just a link is not an answer. Links die and when this one does your answer becomes useless. Please summarize here, or your answer may be deleted. (Like it happened to the guy who blatantly said "so the answer is no, I won't summarize it here.")

Comment: It's not "you can put two in antiparallel", you **HAVE TO** put a diode in antiparallel, or your LED will be killed by the first half cycle reverse voltage. Might explode.

Comment: Has an LED sufficient isolation between mains and its housing? In other words, assumed that all wiring is safely put away, is it still safe to touch the LED house?

Comment: @jippie I wouldn't use this kind of supply for anything that is completely sealed away from the user. I've seen these in consumer products like chirsitmass tree lights and toasters. In general, as i understand it, impedance provided by capacitor drops voltage to safe level, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @miceuz - I'm not going to touch that capacitor. What's even worse is that the other end goes directly to the LED, and that might as well be the phase (like it's drawn in the schematic).

Comment: @miceuz - in the last diagram:-http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzw19.png what is the specification of resistance.

Comment: @miceuz - in the last diagram what is the specification for resistance.

Comment: resistor here is just to limit an inrush current into a capacitor, something like 10 ohm should do